# Конвертация из accdb в mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, access

Подскажите как конвертировать БД .accdb  в формат .sql
гуглить пробовал толком ничего не нашел,мб у кого есть 100% варианты

Comment: Не пробовал. Создаёшь базу mysql. настраиваешь соединение ODBC там, где акцез запускается. В контекстном меню акцеза есть функция экспортировать - по идее должно сработать.

Comment: @4per пробовал не  получилось

Comment: а что именно не получилось?

Comment: @4per руки кривые наверное)